# Sharepoint 2013 SP1 not available

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

Service Pack 1 for SharePoint 2013 has been pulled by Microsoft, however I now face an interesting dilemma:  I have a DB backup, and am trying to re-instantiate the server it should be attached to, however, as SP1 is not installed in the SharePoint 2013 instance the DB file shows no content.

Does anyone know of a location from which I can donwload the service pack?

(I am aware it is flawed, however as a stopgap to retrieve the data and create a non sp1 version of the sp2013 instance I still need to have SP1 available at least temporarily, however I do not possess a local copy (it was on the old now corrupt server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu can download still Sharpeoint 2013 SP 1 slipstream, the bug found by microsoft only affect SP1 package, but not the slipstream package, so if you need to install a sharepoint farm with sp 1 to restore some databases then this is the only solution you have.

Comment: Knew about the slipstreamed version, however it can be impractical as a first port of call to remove and re-install SP2013 Server to replace with SP2013 Foundation with SP1. Still, cheers and looks like you may get the answer if no-one has any alternative involving SP1 on its own :)